# Change Google Cloud Dataflow BigQuery Priority

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Beam job running on Google Cloud DataFlow that reads data from BigQuery. When I run the job it takes minutes for the job to start reading data from the (tiny) table. It turns out the dataflow job sends of a BigQuery job which runs in BATCH mode and not in INTERACTIVE mode. How can I switch this to run immediately in Apache Beam? I couldn't find a method in the API to change the priority.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a Googler will correct me, but no, you cannot change this from `BATCH` to `INTERACTIVE` because it's not exposed by Beam's API.

From `org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO.java` ([here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/b8c32d05521f8a943d04b4351528863b3babe58c/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/BigQueryIO.java#L957)):

```
private void executeQuery(
    String executingProject,
    String jobId,
    TableReference destinationTable,
    JobService jobService) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  JobReference jobRef = new JobReference()
      .setProjectId(executingProject)
      .setJobId(jobId);

  JobConfigurationQuery queryConfig = createBasicQueryConfig()
      .setAllowLargeResults(true)
      .setCreateDisposition("CREATE_IF_NEEDED")
      .setDestinationTable(destinationTable)
      .setPriority("BATCH") <-- NOT EXPOSED
      .setWriteDisposition("WRITE_EMPTY");

  jobService.startQueryJob(jobRef, queryConfig);
  Job job = jobService.pollJob(jobRef, JOB_POLL_MAX_RETRIES);
  if (parseStatus(job) != Status.SUCCEEDED) {
    throw new IOException(String.format(
        "Query job %s failed, status: %s.", jobId, statusToPrettyString(job.getStatus())));
  }
}
```

If it's really a problem for you that the query is running in `BATCH` mode, then one workaround could be:

1. Using the BigQuery API directly, roll your own initial request, and set the priority to `INTERACTIVE`.
2. Write the results of step 1 to a temp table
3. In your Beam pipeline, read the temp table using `BigQueryIO.Read.from()`

Comment: Yeah unfortunately that workaround won't work as I need my ETL job to start at the time of schedule not at some point in the future. Thanks for the  idea though.

Comment: I don't follow. Why exactly would this not work for you?

Comment: I would have thought that by moving the BigQueryIO to step 2 we'll still have to wait for that job to start.

Comment: You would do it in your pipeline code, before constructing and running your pipeline i.e Your scheduled cron kicks off your pipeline. First thing you do is create the table. Then run your pipeline pointing at it.

Comment: At the time the pipeline runs, it will still be running in BATCH mode and therefore slow.

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me again. What will still be running in "BATCH" mode?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145644/discussion-between-graham-polley-and-jimmy).

Answer (score 0):

You can configure to run the queries with "Interactive" priority by passing a priority parameter. Check this [Github example](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.java#L595) for details.

Please note that you might be reaching one of the [BigQuery limits and quotas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas) as when you use batch, if you ever hit a rate limit, the query will be queued and retried later. As opposed to the interactive ones, when if these limits are hit, the query will fail immediately. This is because BigQuery assumes that an interactive query is something you need run immediately.